# Execute test cases from Rally

Tags: rally

I am wondering if we can run a test case from Rally. I understand we can add test cases, add defects etc using java/Rest Rally API but can we invoke a test case from Rally? Reason behind asking is because I want to automate the entire process of a QA cycle  viz. Test case addition>>Test case execution>>Test case result report. 
Please show some light.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Executing a testcase is really just creating a new TestCaseResult object associated to that test case.  You can also optionally associate the TestCaseResult with a TestSet, if you are executing your testcases within the context of an iteration.

I'd probably add a custom string field to your TestCase object that is the name or path of your automation script.  Then at any point your test process (whether wired up in a CI system or some other manner) you can read that test case, find the script, execute it and add a TestCaseResult based on the output.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @Kyle, I have tried adding test cases using a Rest client and java took kit, they were successful. My next moves are the following: 
 1. Link a test case to an automated test script (mapping)
 2. "Run" the test case which will "automatically" trigger an automation script (e.g. selenium script) test and add a result. No manual intervention. The run option can be a button or alike which when clicked can trigger a script. So all automated.